# How to display datagridview cell data in the textbox of another form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I make the cell contentClickEvent of my datagridview to open another form and display the cell data on the textbox of that opened form?

```
Private Sub Formbackground()
        Dim formBackground As Form = New Form()

        Try

            Using uu As AddSupplier = New AddSupplier()
                formBackground.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
                formBackground.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
                formBackground.Opacity = 0.5R
                formBackground.BackColor = Color.Black
                formBackground.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
                formBackground.TopMost = True
                formBackground.Location = Me.Location
                formBackground.ShowInTaskbar = False
                formBackground.Show()
                uu.Owner = formBackground
                uu.ShowDialog()
                formBackground.Dispose()
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            formBackground.Dispose()
        End Try
End Sub

Dim key = 0

Private Sub suppliersDGV_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles suppliersDGV.CellContentClick

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = suppliersDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim low As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)


        AddSupplier.txtSupplier.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        AddSupplier.txtPhone.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        AddSupplier.txtAddress.Text = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString

        If AddSupplier.txtAddress.Text = "" Then
            key = 0
        Else
            key = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        End If
        Formbackground()
End Sub
```

I was expecting that when the Addsupplier Form to load with the cell data in the textboxes

Comment: Too many ways. Do you want ANY grid, any single record to display - you can do some dynamic controls. Do you want specific form of the record? - you can pass a model or datatable reference with record index. Or binding information. This is like too many options

Comment: You can have many instances of the `AddSupplier` form. VB.Net gives you a default instance that you set in the CellContentClick() method, but you show a different instance (uu) in the FormBackground() method.

Comment: You should read all three parts of [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).